# How we can generate html report in cucumber latest version(3.2.0) with protractor-cucumber framework

Tags: protractor

Since cucumber 3 removed the registerHandler and registerListener , how we can generate html report in cucumber 3.2.0.I have used below code for generating json report in cucumber 2.

```
defineSupportCode(function({ registerListener }) {
var JsonFormatter = new Cucumber.JsonFormatter();

JsonFormatter.log = function(string) {
  var outputDir = 'testreports/report';
  var fileName = 'cucumber-report.json';
  var targetJson = path.resolve(outputDir, fileName); 

    if (fse.existsSync(outputDir)) {
        fse.moveSync(outputDir, outputDir + '_' + moment().format('YYYYMMDD_HHmmss'), {
           overwrite: true
        });
    }
fse.outputFileSync(targetJson, string);

};
registerListener(JsonFormatter);
});
```

and used below code for html report

```
defineSupportCode(function({ registerHandler }) {
registerHandler('AfterFeatures', function(features, callback) {
    var options = {
        theme: 'bootstrap',
        jsonFile: 'testreports/report/cucumber-report.json',
        output: 'testreports/report/cucumber-report.html',
        reportSuiteAsScenarios: true,            
    };
    reporter.generate(options);
    callback();
});
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what will be replaced one for registerListener and registerHandler in cucumber 3?Any one having any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do following changes:

**1)** set `cucumberOpts.format` in protractor conf file

```
cucumberOpts: {
   format: ["json:reports/report/cucumber/cucumber-report.json"],
```

here `reports/report/cucumber/cucumber-report.json` is the `cucumber json file path`, you must specify a path at here.

framework will generate it automatically with results' json data as file content when all scenarios execute complete.

**2)** create parent folder of `cucumber json file path` before test framework load if parent folder not exist

Option 1: put create parent folder code at head of protractor conf file.

Option 2: create a Protractor plugin implement interface: `setup()`, which will be executed before test framework load.

```
// plugin: create-report-folder.js
var moment = require("moment");
var fse = require("fs-extra");

module.exports = {
    setup: function() {
        var reportDir = this.config.options.reportDir;
        if (fse.existsSync(reportDir)) {
            fse.moveSync(
               reportDir, 
               reportDir + "_" + moment().format("YYYYMMDD_HHmmss"),
               { overwrite: true}
            );
        }

        fse.mkdirsSync(reportDir);
    }
};
```

**Note**: both options need to use Sync api to create folder.

**3)** create Protractor plugin implement interface: `postResults` which will be executeed after all scenarios execute complete.

```
// plugin: cucumber-html-reporter.js
var reporter = require("cucumber-html-reporter");

module.exports = {
    postResults: function() {
        var options = {
            theme: "bootstrap",
            jsonFile: this.config.options.jsonFile,
            output: this.config.options.htmlFile,
            reportSuiteAsScenarios: true
        };

        reporter.generate(options);
    }
};
```

**Note**: I tried generate cucumber html report in cucumber `AfterAll` hook, but failed, seems Cucumber JsonFormater generate cucumber json file is Async, when `AfterAll` hook start execute, cucumber json file have not create yet.

I'm keeping look into `formatOption`, should be a way to change JsonFormater generate cucumber json file to Sync, then we can use `AfterAll` hook.

**4)** set plugins in protractor conf file

```
// protractor conf file
exports.config = {
    plugins: [
        // plugin to create report parent folder
        {
            path: "supports/create-report-folder.js",
            options: {
                reportDir: "reports/report/cucumber"
            }
        }

        // plugin to generate cucumber html report
        {
            path: "supports/cucumber-html-reporter.js",
            options: {
                jsonFile: "reports/report/cucumber/cucumber-report.json",
                htmlFile: "reports/report/cucumber/cucumber-report.html"
            }
        }
    ]
```

A workable scaffold for `Protractor + Cucumber4 + HTML Report` at [my github](https://github.com/yongcy/automation/tree/master/protractor/protractor-cucumber4-scaffold)

The scaffold for `Protractor + Cucumber3 + HTML Report` on my local has some dependency campatible issue, I'm looking into that in case you must use Cucumber 3.

**5)** If you use multiCapabilities, you can use below package to generate report:

[protractor-multiple-cucumber-html-reporter-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-multiple-cucumber-html-reporter-plugin)

Comment: The above code is helpful but we have one issue with the report.The latest report is not having the name with current date&time.The latest report is laying with name "report".we need to generate latest report having current time append.

Comment: It's as expected, the latest report files will be generated in "report" folder, if you run script again, the "report" folder for last time will be changed to "report_date_time", and a new "report" folder will created for new running.  It's simple to change the logic in support/create-report-folder.js to meet your requiement on report folder.

Comment: I have changed my support/create-report-folder.js as module.exports = { setup: function() { var reportDir = this.config.options.reportDir + "_" + moment().format("YYYYMMDD_HHmmss"); fse.mkdirsSync(reportDir);} };
but i got an error "Unhandled rejection Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open "F:\autom
ation\reports\report\cucumber\cucumber-report.json"  ".so how can i generate report having latest time append for latest report.

Comment: I did the change, get the latest code should work for you.

Comment: Its useful.Thanks young.

Comment: I have 1 more doubt.Can't we generate html report if we running the script in multiple browsers? I have specified multiCapabilities: [                      
 { 'browserName': 'chrome'
  }, { 'browserName': 'firefox'
  },{ 'browserName': 'internet explorer'
  }], in the config file.And when i am running, i got an error "Unable to parse cucumberjs output into json: 'reports/report_20180208_113403/cucumber-report.json' { Error: reports/report_20180208_113403/cucumber-report.json: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\automation\reports\report_20180208_113403\cucumber-report.json'"

Answer (score 0):

If the location of protractor.conf.js is not at the same level as node_modules then the cucumberOpts.format path would be relative to its current file location and the protractor-multiple-cucumber-html-reporter-plugin looks for the json files relative to parent root folder and warns about json file is not found.

To solve this provide absolute path of the json file to cucumberOpts.format like below. This is applicable if you're using cucumber for e2e testing in Angular applications where the protractor.conf.js is normally present inside e2e folder.

```
cucumberOpts: {
    require: [path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'e2e/steps/*.ts')],
    format: 'json:'+ path.resolve(process.cwd() + '/reports/cucumber-ui-reports.json')
}
```